# How to upgrade Rancher 2.4, created by quicksteps on Digital Ocean

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, digital-ocean, rancher

some weeks ago we created our rancher installation on Digital Ocean by following these steps: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/quick-start-guide/deployment/digital-ocean-qs/

Now we want to upgrade rancher, but cannot figure how to do it properly...
When we follow: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/other-installation-methods/single-node-docker/single-node-upgrades/ we cannot find any rancher/rancher images on our server, but many other server components - so we don't know how to backup our old installation?

When I run docker ps, I get following:

```sh
root@quickstart-rancher-server:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS     NAMES
544c00cb4b57   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 16 hours ago   Up 16 hours             k8s_POD_metrics-server-786cd99c65-tc6h2_kube-system_928b179a-5c99-4891-bbf2-91f7419c8762_0
13874a0fdfae   6c3b998b4acf                           "run.sh"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_agent_cattle-node-agent-hbwf6_cattle-system_278d66ad-eecf-4f22-ad1d-ec38cb68ab6a_9
1b3b2521d6b6   6c3b998b4acf                           "run.sh"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_cluster-register_cattle-cluster-agent-dd78489f5-8ts7l_cattle-system_bc1edb78-d112-4d73-9c51-8b3e11a5c69f_10
ee46c2ab70eb   cd72fe6cf6de                           "/app/cmd/cainjector…"   40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_cert-manager_cert-manager-cainjector-6d9776489b-ktfbp_cert-manager_dac0c6c2-c943-4b7a-9a15-6b484c5b790c_5
710ea27c7a59   3129a2ca29d7                           "/configmap-reload -…"   40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_config-reloader_alertmanager-cluster-alerting-0_cattle-prometheus_1994bb7d-a568-416b-9229-003915af3856_3
1cf1900c521d   0881eb8f169f                           "/bin/alertmanager -…"   40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_alertmanager_alertmanager-cluster-alerting-0_cattle-prometheus_1994bb7d-a568-416b-9229-003915af3856_3
2fbd4e01de09   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_cert-manager-cainjector-6d9776489b-ktfbp_cert-manager_dac0c6c2-c943-4b7a-9a15-6b484c5b790c_3
2de48ffbbcf0   94634a50f6be                           "/bin/operator --kub…"   40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_prometheus-operator_prometheus-operator-monitoring-operator-5945986778-w9ql6_cattle-prometheus_d43e737a-0fa2-498d-833e-024ff2dde899_3
dab4649ffcb6   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_alertmanager-cluster-alerting-0_cattle-prometheus_1994bb7d-a568-416b-9229-003915af3856_3
3ca174bef91d   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_prometheus-operator-monitoring-operator-5945986778-w9ql6_cattle-prometheus_d43e737a-0fa2-498d-833e-024ff2dde899_3
5757b339f578   8524c0d7aecc                           "entrypoint.sh --htt…"   40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_rancher_rancher-6b78b4b7fd-vf79w_cattle-system_acf8ece1-00ec-4ed7-bba3-6e2cab12ff03_4
57607f97664b   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_rancher-6b78b4b7fd-vf79w_cattle-system_acf8ece1-00ec-4ed7-bba3-6e2cab12ff03_3
ff6101f011e9   8524c0d7aecc                           "entrypoint.sh --htt…"   40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_rancher_rancher-6b78b4b7fd-fpr28_cattle-system_b5c139c3-5965-4a7d-af7f-9c111cd8987d_4
f29311632cc7   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_cattle-cluster-agent-dd78489f5-8ts7l_cattle-system_bc1edb78-d112-4d73-9c51-8b3e11a5c69f_3
b601715bede8   0bfefe9f649b                           "/opt/bin/flanneld -…"   40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_kube-flannel_canal-686xb_kube-system_893670dd-6a6d-45af-b085-593246a6324b_3
58d769045496   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_rancher-6b78b4b7fd-fpr28_cattle-system_b5c139c3-5965-4a7d-af7f-9c111cd8987d_4
1ddd479162c4   8524c0d7aecc                           "entrypoint.sh --htt…"   40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_rancher_rancher-6b78b4b7fd-24ksk_cattle-system_2cb0d382-a54e-473f-83e0-c3f9dd1d5d21_3
8cd8e3868494   0f351f210d5e                           "start_runit"            40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_calico-node_canal-686xb_kube-system_893670dd-6a6d-45af-b085-593246a6324b_3
a40c8e4f064f   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_rancher-6b78b4b7fd-24ksk_cattle-system_2cb0d382-a54e-473f-83e0-c3f9dd1d5d21_4
9dab9da0aca9   b5af743e5984                           "/server"                40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_default-http-backend_default-http-backend-65dd5949d9-tvd2n_ingress-nginx_15e0d0d6-1636-4e66-ace1-71df6e77edf3_1
9f7bf296a594   4f1064cf7caf                           "/cluster-proportion…"   40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_autoscaler_coredns-autoscaler-79599b9dc6-ptxsv_kube-system_97deb9ae-5c7d-4571-aba1-0c799452dd4c_1
772e90ff9d22   bfe3a36ebd25                           "/coredns -conf /etc…"   40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_coredns_coredns-6f85d5fb88-nfd82_kube-system_69905ba3-4f14-4269-8f66-31a29697f80e_1
f063df235cbe   95aca1ef82b8                           "/app/cmd/webhook/we…"   40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_cert-manager_cert-manager-webhook-6d6d6f9-82fwl_cert-manager_5602b1bd-e34c-4ae8-9212-a6d79e8b25e3_3
8f3ee34f961d   7f4f8cd3e8da                           "/app/cmd/controller…"   40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_cert-manager_cert-manager-d7d8fb5c9-kvwqh_cert-manager_06569895-a76e-46e3-895a-515e4a1d2f30_5
f1ced412e7d0   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_coredns-autoscaler-79599b9dc6-ptxsv_kube-system_97deb9ae-5c7d-4571-aba1-0c799452dd4c_1
70023081bcc2   03feeb39a75a                           "/usr/bin/kube-contr…"   40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_calico-kube-controllers_calico-kube-controllers-649b7b795b-cz44h_kube-system_2b3f9f8b-1b83-47f2-ad69-9c65213a6067_3
149a39f593a0   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_coredns-6f85d5fb88-nfd82_kube-system_69905ba3-4f14-4269-8f66-31a29697f80e_1
3212637e4c16   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_cert-manager-webhook-6d6d6f9-82fwl_cert-manager_5602b1bd-e34c-4ae8-9212-a6d79e8b25e3_3
e4e1ed885cc7   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_cattle-node-agent-hbwf6_cattle-system_278d66ad-eecf-4f22-ad1d-ec38cb68ab6a_3
b464b2acd66b   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_cert-manager-d7d8fb5c9-kvwqh_cert-manager_06569895-a76e-46e3-895a-515e4a1d2f30_3
47243656e589   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_calico-kube-controllers-649b7b795b-cz44h_kube-system_2b3f9f8b-1b83-47f2-ad69-9c65213a6067_4
3601a19ced30   1f0ca6d99110                           "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_nginx-ingress-controller_nginx-ingress-controller-2hnnk_ingress-nginx_b878997a-a0ad-4a04-8218-6aaedce1e7fb_3
981f7f0b79c7   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_default-http-backend-65dd5949d9-tvd2n_ingress-nginx_15e0d0d6-1636-4e66-ace1-71df6e77edf3_1
9d36e5bdcac7   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_canal-686xb_kube-system_893670dd-6a6d-45af-b085-593246a6324b_3
e0b84a14767a   rancher/pause:3.2                      "/pause"                 40 hours ago   Up 40 hours             k8s_POD_nginx-ingress-controller-2hnnk_ingress-nginx_b878997a-a0ad-4a04-8218-6aaedce1e7fb_3
bde2d3b1ca15   rancher/hyperkube:v1.19.3-rancher1     "/opt/rke-tools/entr…"   2 months ago   Up 40 hours             kube-proxy
e310c30f6920   rancher/hyperkube:v1.19.3-rancher1     "/opt/rke-tools/entr…"   2 months ago   Up 40 hours             kubelet
0b01640dd217   rancher/hyperkube:v1.19.3-rancher1     "/opt/rke-tools/entr…"   2 months ago   Up 40 hours             kube-scheduler
de6748d3460b   rancher/hyperkube:v1.19.3-rancher1     "/opt/rke-tools/entr…"   2 months ago   Up 40 hours             kube-controller-manager
91957db74850   rancher/hyperkube:v1.19.3-rancher1     "/opt/rke-tools/entr…"   2 months ago   Up 40 hours             kube-apiserver
ef33d1dfa453   rancher/rke-tools:v0.1.65              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 months ago   Up 40 hours             etcd-rolling-snapshots
b16629017fa9   rancher/coreos-etcd:v3.4.13-rancher1   "/usr/local/bin/etcd…"   2 months ago   Up 40 hours             etcd
```

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just removed the old installation and imported the cluster again in the new rancher installation.